# Conditional selection of elements in Selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing a situation where a modal sometimes has a desired button for logging into Facebook and sometimes I have to click 'More Options' to get to the Facebook button. Another hurdle is that the xpath of the `more_options_btn` is the same as one called 'Trouble logging in?' so I added a `[contains(text(),"More Options")]`, but am unsure of the syntax here and cannot find the right approach in the docs. In any case it is throwing an error, which might be caused by the fact that the `button` element does not have text, instead it is nested like this `button > span > text`

Please keep in mind that I want to make my solution as dynamic and robust as possible, but don't have a lot of experience with Selenium yet.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('http://localhost:3000/')

try:
    fb_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/span/div[2]/button')
    fb_btn.click()
except:
    more_options_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/span/button[contains(text(),"More Options")]')
    more_options_btn.click()

    fb_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/span/div[2]/button')
    fb_btn.click()
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Try to change xpath to:

```
//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/span/button[contains(.,"More Options")]
```

It can find the children node of 'button' contains has the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR operator in xpath `|` to match your xpath with multiple condition. I would recommend to use Relative xpath instead of Absolute one.

As you xpath are too lengthy so it would look like this with OR condition

```
//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/span/div[2]/button | //*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/span/button[contains(text(),"More Options")]
```

Answer (score 0):

With a combination from the input above I managed to get it to work. I got rid of a lot of the long xpath. This has the advantage that my code will still work if the order of the buttons change. It will however still break if the text of the buttons changes, so it is a compromise. Here is the result:

```py
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('http://localhost:3000/')
sleep(5)

try:
    fb_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*/button[contains(.,'Log in with Facebook')]").click()
except NoSuchElementException:

    more_options_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[contains(text(), 'More Options')]")
    more_options_btn.click()
    fb_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*/button[contains(.,"Log in with Facebook")]')
    fb_btn.click()
```